# 2 different versions of Guava on different module layers, still step on each other's feet

Tags: java, guava, java-module

Boot layer has a dependency to Guava 10

The app creates a module layer, which has a dependency to Guava 29.

This ends up in:

```
Modules com.google.common and guava export package com.google.common.annotations to module org.checkerframework.checker.qual
```

[Use case: I design an app which can observe plugins - each plugin is independent from each other, and can rely on libraries from different versions. This can create incompatibilities, and I use Guava 10 and 29 as test cases on how to manage this complexity]

Comment: possible to push guava 10 to classpath?

Comment: I doubt that you can have a different version in another module layer when the conflicting version is in the *boot layer*.

Comment: yes I fear that's the issue. I am going to try a version of my app where the boot layer is almost empty, all the components of my app (and their conflicting library versions) will be in different services loaded via ServiceLoader. I'll report here if that works.

Comment: Module layers are inherited. You need to put Guava 10 and 29 into two separate child layers.